# What are these kinds of typography called?

Tags: typography, page-layout, terminology, typesetting, typefaces

While talking about typography, we are often presented with beautiful graphics made with types and all. Although I find them very creative, I personally don't have a knack for those. I rather prefer simple words, sentences, and paragraphs organized and aligned with hierarchy and space distribution, in digital or print media. It's amazing how sober and beautiful pure texts can be on a humble piece of invoice or newspaper. See the examples for a clearer idea. My question is: are these also part of typography or do they have some other name? I would like to know and read more about these but I can't begin before I know what I'm looking for.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Designing how a page should look is usually called [**layout**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_layout) and is not usually considered a part of typography but typography is often considered a necessary skill to do a good page layout.

Page layout requires a good sense of composition. Normally one would be required to compose not just text but also graphics, photographs, background color and/or images etc.

In modern software development the job title of someone doing this is usually just Graphic Designer or UI/UX Designer. In traditional print it would be Graphic Designer or Art Director.

Using pure text without any background or colors is just one style of layout. If you want to specialize in layouts you will be expected to also handle colors. However, do note that choosing not to use colors or having very minimal use of colors is one way of handling colors and there are well known designers who work mostly in black and white.

---

You mentioned being interested in reading more about the topic. Googling ["page layout design"](https://www.google.com/search?q=page%20layout%20design) is a good way to get started but there is a lot of noise and "what is layout" types of articles on the internet so finding really good content is not easy. I'd suggest (if you're not in lockdown) going to a book store and browse the Art/Design section. As in a lot of things related to art, most of the things you'll find tend to be examples of other people's designs rather than theory. But that's just how art works: you take inspiration from what you see.

Comment: I totally agree with the part about learning from examples rather than theory. In page layout there are only so many "knobs to turn" (font, leading, margins, formats, columns, lines etc.). All different layout styles come from the endless different combinations of those. So if you know the basic tools of the toolbox, you can easily recreate any style you see.

Answer (score 7):

I would say overall the samples are all **[Minimalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimalism), [2](https://creativemarket.com/blog/minimalist-design-trend)**.

Using the least amount of objects possible to convey information in an interesting manner.

<sub>(Someone missed the fact that "design" is misspelled in one of the samples -- ouch!)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

No specific name, just different ways of flowing content into documents, all under the broader field of editorial design.

Comment: Interesting. Does the term "editorial design" apply to the flow of the content on digital media? Because as I see it, it can be applied far beyond just "editorials". This is visualization of information hierarchy.

Comment: I guess it does. Editorial design has been around long before websites have, but generally speaking it serves the same purpose in both print vs digital.

Answer (score 4):

It's a branch of typography called layouts. The key concept here is the use of grids which is a technique for inducing alignment, hierarchy and balance in design using whitespace.

If you're interested more, please head to this website:
[Thinking With Type](http://thinkingwithtype.com/) . It's based upon a classic book by Ellen Lupton.

You can see similar examples of what you shared [here](http://thinkingwithtype.com/grid/).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to go to your public library they should have books on layout and design. You can probably search their catalog online. If you are interested in print, as opposed to web based, layout you are looking for books in the vicinity of 686.2.

Hint: Searching the catalog will probably bring up mostly web based design books. Search for "typography layout".

Answer (score 2):

What are you looking for is "grid based layout design" - This kind of focus on graphics is mainly appreciated in the editorial world  (look for "Editorial Graphic Design" ) - so related to publications/printing for obvious reasons. In Italy I also have heard it being called Swiss style even though "minimalism"- as I see it being called here- is very well appreciated in higher level graphic schools all over europe.
Lately with the wide support for grid systems on web pages (go check css grids and bootstrap)  things are starting to get more interesting in the digital enviroment too tho, so is no more confined to printing.
Usually what is considered the "Bible" of the modern grid based layout is the book from the late 70s/early 80s : 
"Grid Systems in Graphic Design/ Raster Systeme Fur Die Visuele Gestaltung"
of Josef Müller-Brockmann, a swiss graphic designer.
You can easily find it online, btw, so if you like the style go and check it cause it's interesting.